# What are "real stores" called in English, as opposed to "online stores"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

In a piece of software, what would I call a store that sells items to the public in real life as opposed to an *online store* (ie. a health-food store).

It will look like this:

> 1. ____ Store
> 2. Online Store

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The fashionable phrase is [brick and mortar business](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_and_mortar_business).

Comment: +1; This is exactly what I would call it. You don't strictly need "business" here, either. A brick and mortar store/building/etc all work.

Comment: @dino: Something like "Brick and mortar office supply store" or "brick and mortar book store." The phrase would be "brick and mortar [topic] [store]." You can use "business" or "building" in place of "store": "I prefer shopping at brick and mortar businesses."

Comment: I thought it was usually pluralised, i.e. "brick**s** and mortar store." 'Brick' is not usually a mass noun.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: It isn't always a mass noun, but it can be (e.g. "house made of brick"), and is here.

Comment: "That's a lot of brick" is perfectly acceptable, but so it "that's a lot of bricks".

Comment: "Bricks and mortar" became common than "brick and mortar" some time ago according the Google N-gram Viewer but both are still popular. But keep in mind that this phrase has an older sense relating to property investment in contrast to less tangible forms of investment or speculation.

Comment: be careful that your audience -- especially older or less technically savvy ones -- might misunderstood brick and mortar store as being a store that sells actual bricks and mortars.

Comment: How about "bricks-and-mortar"?

Comment: Great answer, but not perfect for the situation it is to be used in.

Comment: @SamB: In UK at least, *bricks-and-mortar* is still a common term relating to property investment (certainly until a couple of years ago when house prices started falling for the first time in a generation). No particular 'professional financier' overtones either - anybody might say that taking out a mortgage is putting money in *bricks-and-mortar* rather than paying (lower) rent and saving the surplus thereby made available.

Answer (score 19):

Physical store is a possibility.

Actually, I would just say "Online" (online store) and "Store" (real store).

Comment: Although both are "real".

Answer (score 13):

These are sometimes called [*High Street stores*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Street) in British English.

Comment: Or "High street shops", "shop" being more common than "store" for the things.

Comment: @Colin, yep, I'd say "shop", but I wanted to emphasise the High St bit.

Comment: This changes the meaning. Physical store could be a Wallmart, which most definitely is **not** High Street store.

Comment: @vartec: you're right on both points, but that doesn't affect how I've experienced the phrase being used in recent years.  It's common in conversation, where familiarity can trump precision, but probably less relevant to the OP's software.

Answer (score 12):

You'll also see non-online outlets referred to as the following:

- traditional retail stores
- conventional retail stores
- retail
- local stores/shops
- offline stores

Answer (score 2):

[Henry's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23482/what-is-real-stores-called-in-english-as-opposite-of-online-store/23483#23483) answer is dead on but some stores have their own variations. The board game community calls their stores the FLGS for Friendly-Local-Gaming-Store.

Comment: @MrHen: If OP was working on software for a chain of stores specialising in board games, they'd have probably have told him in the project spec that they wanted to be called FLGS's. But then he wouldn't be able to re-sell the package to, say, music stores.

Comment: @Fumble: The takeaway is that some specialties have their own terms. Any any software package that hardcodes a term like that is designed incorrectly.

Comment: @MrHen: Tell me about it. I wrote software for bus companies to analyse Route Revenue. Or Service Revenue as some would have it. Put it all in the User Config settings, and hope they don't specify something too long to display properly in your page design.

Comment: @MrHen: What about FumbleFingers' advice `STOCKIST`?

Comment: @dino: I have never heard the word STOCKIST and have no idea what it means.

Comment: Adding to MrHen's point, we should also consider that regions have their own terms as well.  Stockist is a British term that I, as an American, have also never heard.  If the OP's usage is not strictly in GB then it may be confusing to use that term.

Comment: There's always something to learn here. Off the cuff I'd have guessed **stockist** was more US than UK, but you guys obviously know what words you use. For what it's worth, NGrams seems to suggest it's always been more common in US, but briefly shot to prominence in UK in the 50's. Which accords with my sense of it being a bit 'dated'.

Answer (score 2):

You can call them `Physical Stores`.

There is a nice usage example in the [Brick and mortar business wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_and_mortar_business)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're asking because in your 'piece of software' you want to present these two store types so the user can pick one.

In which case you don't really want something 'quirky' like *bricks-and-mortar*, and things like *traditional/conventional retail store* would look a bit verbose.

But the user can see the alternatives, and he already knows what an **Online Store** is. Just call the other type **Stockist**. I'm sure it would be readily understood without being thought odd.

Comment: if you are right, that's exactly what i am looking for. Just let me know if you have any good example (I mean, i want to be sure to use this word `STOCKIST`).

Comment: I'd consider "Stockist" quirky, have read brick-and-mortar much more often than "Stockist".

Comment: My dictionary lists stockish as Brit. and my spellchecker doesn't think it is a word. The definition appears to be something that sells one type of goods and has no mention of a physical or non-physical store.

Comment: @MrHen: Well obviously I must have been a bit parochial in suggesting it. I knew the word well enough, and thought it was primarily US anyway, so it just seemed like a suitable choice for a *short* word in this context. Apparently it's even more 'quirky' to US speakers than *brick and mortar* is to me. But it's impossible to argue against the number of upvotes that has.

Comment: @dino beytar: I use Google Instant, but I'm sure I've never included **Stockist** in a search term until a minute ago. Having typed **wahl clippers sto**, the four alternative completions were **stopped working**, **stores**, **storm**, and **stockist**. I'm now off to see what on earth **wahl clippers storm** is all about, but I think that's proof enough that some (UK, at least) people expect to buy things from **stockists**.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'Local store' is the simplest and best sounding way to phrase it.

Comment: unless it's not local.